# Loading large objects in JavaScript through a variable vs external file

Tags: javascript

Is it more efficient to load a 300KB object into a JavaScript variable like this:

```
var data = <?php echo $jsonData; ?>
```

Or, grab it from a file like so:

```
d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
  //Do Something
});
```

As far as performance is concerned? I have looked around, but have not found anything accept explanation on how to get data from files using JS or JS variables in general. I have large JSON string being exposed to my JS code and it is slowing things down, but there is the issue of making too many http calls. Which approach is going to be computationally optimal?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It probably doesn't make much difference. The bottleneck is copying the data over the network, it doesn't matter whether it's in one file or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data transport will take the same amount of time. The only difference is how soon the user can interact with the page. If you load the data inline, it may block the rest of the page load. If you load it in code, you can choose when the user is going to take the hit.

You're best to load it in code. That way you can at least give the user an indication that something is going on.